# Convergence in norm of a sequence with indicator functions

Tags: real-analysis

I'm just starting to learn about sequence and function spaces, and there was an exercise marked as "trivial" in my lecture notes that I'm having trouble with:

Let $x := (x_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers in $l^2(\mathbb{R})$, i.e. $||x||_2:=\sqrt{\underset{k\in\mathbb{N}}{\sum}x_k^2}<\infty$. For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $x^{(n)} := (x_k^{(n)})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $l^2(\mathbb{R})$ with terms defined as: 
    \begin{align*}
 x_k^{(n)} := x_k\mathbf{1}_{\{0\leq k \leq n\}}\mathbf{1}_{\{|x_k|\leq n\}}=
 \begin{cases}
 x_k & \text{if } k \leq n \text{ and } |x_k| \leq n \\
 0 & \text{otherwise}
 \end{cases}
 \end{align*}
    Is it true that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}||x^{(n)}-x||_2 = 0$?

(i.e. that
$\forall\varepsilon > 0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that  $\forall n \geq N$, $\sqrt{\underset{k\in\mathbb{N}}{\sum}(x^{(n)}_k-x_k)^2}< \varepsilon $)

---

I suspect that the answer should be "yes", and so far, I have managed to show the following:

(A) $x^{(n)}$ converges pointwise to $x$, i.e. that for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}x^{(n)}_k = x_k$.

(B) $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}||x^{(n)}-x||_1 = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\bigg(\underset{k\in\mathbb{N}}{\sum}|x^{(n)}_k-x_k|\bigg) = 0$ implies $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}||x^{(n)}-x||_2 = 0$.

However, I am unsure how to move on from here. Currently, I have tried doing the following "proof":

"Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Then, by (A), it must be true that for all $l \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists some $M_l\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $m\geq M_l$, we have $|x_l^{(m)}-x_l| < \frac{1}{2^{l+1}}\varepsilon$. It follows by the [basic series comparison test](https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Basic_comparison_test) that for all $m\geq\text{sup}\{M_l|l\in\mathbb{N}\}$, we have $\underset{l\in\mathbb{N}}{\sum}|x_l^{(m)}-x_l| < \underset{l\in\mathbb{N}}{\sum}\frac{1}{2^{l+1}}\varepsilon=\varepsilon$. Hence, $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\bigg(\underset{k\in\mathbb{N}}{\sum}|x^{(n)}_k-x_k|\bigg) = 0$. Using (B) therefore gives us the desired result."

I believe that this proof is wrong because I have asserted the existence of $\text{sup}\{M_l|l\in\mathbb{N}\}$ without actually proving it, but based on my intuition, I think that $\text{sup}\{M_l|l\in\mathbb{N}\}$ does not actually exist, since it seems like we can make $\varepsilon$ arbitrarily small in order to make $M_l$ arbitrarily large (and so we can't use the axiom of completeness here). I suspect that the condition $|x_k|\leq n$ should somehow be useful, but I can't think of a way to use it, and on the other hand, I am unable to think of a counterexample to disprove the original statement.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction or tell me what I have missed out so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *Then by (A), it must be true...* ... is clearly wrong!

Take
$$x_l^{(n)} =\begin{cases}
1 & l=n\\
0 & l \neq n
\end{cases}$$

$(x^{(n)})_{n \in \mathbb N}$ converges pointwise to the always vanishing sequence, but doesn’t satisfy your condition as for all $l \in \mathbb N$ you have $x_l^{(l)} =1$.

Now your intution that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}||x^{(n)}-x||_2 = 0$ is valid. The argument to prove it is that as $x \in \ell^2(\mathbb R)$, the sequence $x$ is eventually bounded by $1$. It implies that it exists $N \in \mathbb N$ such that for $n \ge N$
$$x_l^{(n)} =\begin{cases}
x_l & l \le n\\
0 & l > n
\end{cases}$$ and therefore $\Vert x^{(n)} - x \Vert_2 = \sum\limits_{l >n} x_l^2$ which is converging to zero as $x \in \ell^2(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! I agree with you that there exists $N \in\mathbb{N}$ such that for $n\geq N$, we have $x_l^{(n)} = \begin{cases} x_l & l\leq n \\ 0 & l>n \end{cases}$, but it is not clear to me how this shows the desired result (that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}||x^{(n)}-x||_2 = 0$. It seems like your statement works for each term in the sequence, but the desired result is a summation of infinite terms, so I'm not sure how you made that jump.

Comment: @Keno I edited my answer to provide an additional argument.

Answer (score 2):

Use the dominated convergence theorem.

$|x^{(n)}_k -x_k | \le 2 |x_k| $, and $(x^{(n)}_k -x_k) \to 0$, hence
$\|x^{(n)} -x\|^2  = \int |x^{(n)}_k -x_k |^2 d |\cdot| \to 0$ (counting measure
on $\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've never seen this theorem before, but after a bit of reading, it looks like a pretty powerful one that can be used here. I presume we can just use (B) from my original question to prove the desired result then?